# R: creating a barplot depicting a percentage of a percentage in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm having a lot of trouble using my current dataset to create the barplot I need. It seems straightforward enough, but I am getting an error whenever I run my code.

[link to my data set](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7U-Ru5ToQrTd0NyZmxNc0JhMzQ/edit?usp=sharing)

*some background information*

> Percent_Calls is calculated by Call/(Call+Noise)
>
> Percent_Total is calculated by (Call+Noise)/(sum(Call)+sum(Noise));
>
> PercentofCall is calculated by Percent_Calls*Percent_Total

I am trying to create a barplot (with percentages on the y axis) with CRF_Score as the x-variable and the Percent_Total values as the bars. Eventually, I would like to highlight the portion of PercentofCall in Percent_Total.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(FD2_CAna, aes(CRF_Score, fill=Percent_Total)) + geom_bar(binwidth=0.05)
```

The above code usually works for me, however I am getting this error instead:

```
Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

I have tried using `as.factor(x)` as suggested in another thread, but the graph output is not what I need.

[image: It's showing me a gradient of values, and I only need the value as seen in the data.frame to be plotted]

This is more along of lines of what I want, except it was made in JMP. 
[image]

Sorry for the long explanation, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the similar plot to JMP you should use `Percent_Total` as y values and not as the `fill=` values and then in `geom_bar()` use `stat="identity"`.

With your JMP plot it seems that `Percent_Total` is treated as factor and not as numeric variable - you can see it by comparing the height of bars with values 23 and 2 - they are almost the same width. If file `FD2_CAna.csv` is imported properly then values are numeric.

```
FD2_CAna<-read.csv2(file="FD2_CAna.csv",header=T,sep=",",dec=".")
ggplot(FD2_CAna, aes(CRF_Score, Percent_Total)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I should've read the ggplot package info more closely.